# When i try to set a valstep to Slider i get an error AttributeError: Unknown property valstep

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why do i get an Attribute Error for valstep? I am new to programming but it seems to me that Slider should take valstep as an argument?
`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.25)
a0 = 1
f0 = 1
t = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.001)
delta_f = 5.0
s = a0 * np.cos(f0 * t)
l, = plt.polar(t, s, lw=1)
ax.set_rmin(-a0)
ax.set_rgrids([-a0/2,0,a0/2], [])
ax.grid(True)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.1, 0.15, 0.8, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 12.0, valinit=f0, valstep=0.2)


plt.show()
```

Here i get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property valstep
```

Comment: Yes, ```valstep``` is a valid argument of ```Slider```. Your code runs without problem on my machine. What version of ```matplotlib```  do you have? You may need an update.

Comment: Yes i have updated it now it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using

`user~$ python plot.py`

to run the code on my terminal changing it to

`user~$ python3 plot.py`

did the trick.

You can also use shbang (Linux): `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in the 1st line of the script